# How is life cycle of static var?

Tags: swift, static

I have a static variable which looks like below:

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {
    static var commonSet: Set<String> = []
}
```

As long as I understand, this static variable works like a global var named `AViewController.commonSet` and alive while app is alive(even in background).

However I'm getting unexpected logs which only can happen when the static var is re-initiated while app is running. I want to know when static var is initiated and there's any chance static var is re-initiated.

Comment: A static will be initialized when you first access it, and never again. Clearly, though, the way you've defined this, it's possible that you manually reset it (e.g. there's nothing to stop you from doing `AViewController.commonSet = []` elsewhere). Now, if the app is terminated at any point (e.g. user went to another app and eventually it was jettisoned due to memory pressure), the next time you run it, it will obviously be initialized again.

Comment: @Rob What if it is 'let' not 'var'?

Comment: Same thing (though an empty `Set` that is immutable is worthless ... you could never add anything to the set).

Comment: I suspect you should try to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that manifests the problem. First, it's a lot easier for someone to help you. Second, in the process of creating the reproducible example, you'll often figure out the source of the problem (because you'll keep adding things until you see the behavior manifested, thereby figuring out what caused the problem). But we can't help you unless you share a (concise) example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. It is happening like 1/30k ratio.(number is based on event tracking). I'll update if I get more information.

Comment: Bottom line, I'm pretty confident the problem is not in the `static`. Either the app was terminated and restarted or you're doing something to manually reset this property or something like that. The `static` properties simply do not just reset themselves.

Comment: @Ryan Like rob said the app was probably terminated at some point. At which the static variables would be lost. You would have to store them in `UserDefaults` and then grab them back when it reinits

Comment: I don't care about a case app terminated. The static var is set in AViewController's viewDidLoad. If app is terminated, it will be set when AViewController is loaded and that is what I intended. I want to know that static var can be reinitiated while app is running.